# My cursor has a wrong and static icon. It no longer shows a standard arrow icon at all

Tags: windows, mouse-cursor

I am on Windows 10 Pro x64 and my cursor is showing as a static text-type mouse cursor. As in when you put the arrow with your mouse in a text document, only that there never was any arrow.

It no longer shows an arrow at all, and the mouse cursor icon is no longer context sensitive.

When I go to an application window edge to resize to window: Still the same text cursor.

When I put the cursor over a link: Still same text cursor icon.

A restart of the computer does not fix it. I have tried another mouse. No change.

It has been like this for a while (maybe 3 weeks), but I don't have specifics regarding how or why this change has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the mouse pointer is a simple setting you can change.

If you right-click an empty portion of your desktop, and choose personalize, it opens the settings for personalization.

On the left, go to Themes, and then on the right locate Mouse cursor.

A new dialog opens with the mouse cursors currently in use. You can try changing the scheme at the top and hit apply to instantly change the scheme to something else in order to see if that changes the cursor. Do not try to change it to the same setting, because then windows will ignore it. You have to change it to something else, hit apply and then optionally change it back and hit apply again.

Comment: Well, you are right.
However, I had tried the normal way, meaning this, which didn't work. It was caused by an unknow bug, which didn't resolve by changing the theme in Windows or manually changing the mouse cursor icon in windows.
I'm sorry to say it resolved itself spontaniously after a while yesterday, so no real resolution to my bug is known.
I have tagged your answer as correct, in case someone else have an issue which can be resolved through Windows menues.

Answer (score 1):

We determined that disconnecting and reconnecting the docking station from a user's laptop resolved the exact same issue with the mouse cursor selection.

Anyone who stumbles across this thread, I recommend you unplug all other peripherals than the mouse and a standard keyboard. Not sure if it matters that the computer was on when these were disconnected.